# What does this expression, 1>0, evalute to (on 64 bit) in C?

Tags: c

To test "What does this expression, 1>0, evalutes to (on 64 bit) in C?" question, I wrote this program.

```
int main()
{
    printf("char=%d", 1>0 );
    return 0;
}
```

- It prints "1". Is it right way to find the expression, 1>0?
- And does operating system bit (64bit) matter? Why did the problem state (on 64 bit)???

Comment: In C a boolean "true" is equivalent to the `int` value `1`.

Comment: __Q1__: yes. __Q2__: no. __Q3__: _Why did the problem state (on 64 bit)?_ This question is meaningless or incomplete or grammatically/semantically so wrong that I (and probably most others) don't understand it. Please correct.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: The OS might have impact on the width of the `int` the expression `1>0` evaluated to.

Comment: @alk yes of course, but using `%d` for the `int` type in `printf`and friends is alwas correct, itn't it? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, `a > b` is an expression of `int` type that is either equal to `0` or `1`. That is not a function of the operating system: of course though the exact nature of an `int` is dependent on your platform.

So `1 > 0` is an `int` with value `1`.

So your code is equivalent to `printf("char=%d", 1);`

Comment: I think I wrote the program to test "What does this expression, 1>0, evalute to (on 64 bit) in C?" wrong. Thanks for your effort

Comment: @JohnBaek no, your program is correct. What makes you think it is wrong?

Comment: I thought I had to test program on 64 bit vs 32 bit. I can't find the point of asking "(on 64-bit)".

Comment: I'm solving essential C questions I should know before learning OS given my professor. I'm really panicked

Comment: @JohnBaek: Have yourself a glass of wine, and read K & R, completing the example exercises. (Note that in C++ the expression is a `bool` type.)

Comment: The problem is I already read the book (I need to re-read it) And watched several series of YouTube video. And still I have no idea what's going on. Do you think these problems are essential to build OS? Is this easy for you? https://tc.gtisc.gatech.edu/cs3210/2017/spring/q/prep.txt

Comment: @JohnBaek well for building an OS, a very good knowledge of the C language is certainly very helpful.

Comment: @JohnBaek the bitness (32 vs. 64) doesn't matter for this question.

Answer (score 4):

According to [C11 Standard, Section 6.5.8: Relational operators](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8) -

> **6.** Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false, The result has type int.

The Footnote (which is very important to understand) says,

> The expression `a<b<c` is not interpreted as in ordinary mathematics. As the syntax indicates, it means `(a<b)<c`; in other words, 'if a is less than b, compare 1 to c; otherwise, compare 0 to c'.

So,

```
printf("char=%d", 1>0 );
```

is evaluated as

```
printf("char=%d", 1 );
```

The same way if,

```
int num = 0xAA;
int mun = 0x55;

printf("char=%d", 0xAA>0x55 );
```

The result will be

```
1
```

Update: The whole confusion about 32-bit vs 64-bit system is irrelevant for this particular issue you are facing. You don't need to consider that as of now.

Answer (score 1):

In C, true is represented by 1(one) or any nonzero value and false is represented by 0(zero). As 1>0 is true you get a 1 which represents true. All relational operators work the same way. It works the same on 16 bit,32 bit and 64 bit machine.